# Querying on a record with different occurrence

Tags: sql, count, group-by, having

I have this scenario

```
|---COL A ------------------COL B----|
|----001 ----------------------X-----|
|----001 ----------------------X-----|
|----002 ----------------------Y-----|
|----002 ----------------------Y-----|
|----003 ----------------------X-----|
|----003 ----------------------Y-----|
|----004 ----------------------X-----|
|----004 ----------------------Z-----|
```

I want to get the records with varying values in `colB`. So as a result I am expecting a result of ids who have different values for column b.

```
003
004
```

meaning 003 has an x and Y , and 004 has an x and a Z

I tried:

```
select colA,count(*) from table group by colA,colB having count(*) >2;
```

looks wrong because it groups those with same A and B

so I removed col b on group by but then it gets all those with same A and disregards whether B is equal or not. I don't know the right syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT colA 
FROM (
    SELECT colA, COUNT(DISTINCT colB) countB
    FROM tableGroup 
    GROUP BY colA
)
WHERE countB > 1
```

Comment: hmm i was avoiding a subselect because im running it with hundreds of thousands of records in production and it might slow down the system will it?

Comment: In that case try Gordon's solution. But I'd test all options for performance; what we may think of as faster may or may not be so, according to the optimisations done by the DMBS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select colA
from t
group by colA
having count(distinct colB) >= 2
```

The key is the `count(distinct)`.

A slightly more efficient form of this is:

```
having min(colB) <> max(colB)
```

However, this does not generalize to more than 2 values.